# iPhoto "A photo Has been found in the iPhoto library that was not imported"

Tags: macos, photos.app

Every Time I launch iPhoto I get the following error message twice... 'A photo Has been found in the iPhoto library that was not imported, would you like to import it now'

So i Click yes and then it appears again, after clicking yes again it goes away and lets me into iPhoto its not the end of the world but gets pretty annoying as it never imports anything and is just pointless and time wasting. Its been appearing on every load of iPhoto for about 6 months now any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Open your iPhoto Library package by Control-clicking on it and selecting "Show Package Contents" from the contextual menu. Look for a folder titled "Importing" or "Import" (NOT Auto Import") and see if it has any photos in it. If it does move it to the Desktop (do not move or rename any other folder/file while in there). Launch iPhoto and the message should be gone.

Check that folder to see if the photos are any you don't have in the library or want. If not, then delete. If so, import again.